# A simple test for degenerate eigenvalues of a holomorphic matrix-valued function?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Consider a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $H(z)$ whose entries are holomorphic functions of a complex parameter $z$ and real on the real axis. It's known, from

> Analytic structure of the eigenvalue problem as used in semiclassical theory of electronically inelastic collisions. P. Pechukas et al., [*J. Chem. Phys.* **64** no. 3, pp. 1099-1105 (1976)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.432297)

that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$ are analytical functions of $z$, except for possible branch points at the degeneracy points of $H$. (More specifically, if two eigenvalue surfaces meet at $z_c$, then doing a full circle around $z_c$ will tend to swap the two eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors.)

**I am looking for a simple way to test for, and find, these degeneracy points**, where two eigenvalues merge into a single root of multiplicity 2.

One way I can think of is to solve the characteristic equation
$$\det(E-H(z))=0$$
for the eigenvalue $E$, and then require that the derivative of the characteristic polynomial also vanish there:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
\det(E-H(z))&=0\\
\frac{d}{dE}\det(E-H(z))&=0
\end{align}\right.\tag1$$
as simultaneous equations of $E$ and $z$.

Pechukas et al., on the other hand, offer an interesting alternative. In $n=3$ dimensions, the characteristic polynomial can be written as
$$\det(E-H(z))=E^3+C_1(z)E^2+C_2(z)E+C_3(z),$$
and the eigenvalues can be written as radical functions of the combination $\alpha^3+\beta^2$, where
$$\alpha=\frac19(3C_2-C_1^2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\beta=\frac{1}{54}(2C_1^3-9C_1C_2+27C_3).$$
More importantly, if one expands 
$$\det(E-H(z))=(E-E_1)(E-E_2)(E-E_3)$$
and sets the coefficients $C_1,C_2,C_3$ to the symmetric products of the roots, the above combination turns out to be (after a bit of computer-assisted algebra)
$$\alpha^3+\beta^2=-\frac1{108}(E_1-E_2)^2(E_2-E_3)^2(E_3-E_1)^2,$$
which vanishes iff $H(z)$ is degenerate.

This approach folds the system (1) into finding the zeros of a single analytical function of $z$, which I think is indeed simpler to work with (and probably easier to handle numerically). However, this form is explicitly tied to the specific representation in three dimensions. **Does it generalize to four or more dimensions?** More specifically, is there a single function that can be obtained directly from $H$ whose zeros are its degeneracy points?

Comment: The discriminant (of the characteristic polynomial). But it ain't so easy for higher degrees.

Comment: @Daniel Is there a way to obtain it directly from the matrix?

Comment: Depends on what you call directly. The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial can be computed "directly" from the matrix entries. The discriminant can be computed from the coefficients of the polynomial. But it gets complicated fast. I don't know if there is a nicer way.